# How to query parse.com REST API from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I have a working curl call:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXXX" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: YYYY" \
  -G \
  --data 'where={"number":1}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Day
```

How do I translate this into an angular $http call? I have tried every permutation I can think of, and it still retrieves every Day object. Base on the documentation, I expected the following to work:

```
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Day',
        data: {"where": {"number": 1}}});
```

---

EDIT:
I updated my code to use the Parse JavaScript SDK as recommended in the accepted solution. I installed it using bower:

```
bower install --save parse
```

In my app.js I initialize Parse:

```
Parse.initialize(parseAppId, parseJavascriptKey);
```

The controller code is a lot more verbose than what I had before, but does work correctly and provides more flexible querying:

```
  var Day = Parse.Object.extend("Day");
  var query = new Parse.Query(Day);
  query.equalTo("number", currentDay);  // Only retrieve objects matching currentDay
  query.include('challenge,quote');  // Related objects
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      console.log("Retrieved object with id: " + results[0].get('id'));
      $scope.day = results[0];
      $scope.$apply();
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Should work. Expose WIRe & HEADER logs and see whats there . Compare to what -v or --asci-trace produce on curl calls

Comment: It turns out I needed to specify 'params' not 'data'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using $http you should be using the parse javascript api instead. https://parse.com/docs/js/guide

Comment: Do you have any specific examples of integrating the parse javascript API into an Ionic (or even plain angularjs) project? I did try integrating the [parse-angular-patch](https://github.com/brandid/parse-angular-patch) module but couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: No. I have done it though. It's really simple. Just include the javascript file and call Parse.initilize: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/web/existing.Then in your services you can perform queries.

Answer (score 2):

While Wayne is 100% correct, [We](http://www.sk8.asia) have decided to go a bit further and wrote a parse-angular seed project for developing web apps. It can be found [here](https://github.com/SK8-PTY-LTD/parse-angular).

After you pulled it, do a `npm install`

As usual, cloud code should go into cloud/main.js, 
express code: cloud/app.js
angular code: cloud/public/js/

Note that: You will need to change your `AppId` and `AppKey` in

config/global.json
cloud/public/js/app.js

Then you should have a nice parse-angular project set up and good to go. 
If there's anything wrong, please feel free to open a pull request. :)